# Unlocking device after factory reset

Tags: sim-unlocking

Device still needs previous google account after factory reset and I don't know the pin or Google account before resetting

Comment: Welcome to the Q&A site Android Enthusiasts Stack Exchange. We have an existing question for the same issue about bypassing Factory Reset Protection. Please take a look at the duplicate question. Thank you.